# cloing object which has reference to another mutable object in java

Tags: java, clone

I am learning java. Here is the code which I wrote as a part of understanding how to clone an object in java...

```
Class Address {
 String city;
 String state;
}

class Customer implements Cloneable {
  String name;
  Address address;

  public Customer(String name, String city, String state) {
    this.name = name;
    address = new Address();
    address.city = city;
    address.state = state;
  }

  public Object clone() {
    Customer coned = null;
    try {
      cloned = super.cloned();
      return cloned; 
    } catch(CloneNotSupportedException e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Here I want to clone a Customer object as follows --

```
Customer customer = new Customer("john", "acity", "astate");
Customer newCustomer = (Customer) customer.clone();
newCustomer.address.city = "bcity";
```

Here comes the problem. As soon as I set a new value for the `city`, it actually updates the original object as well. My goal is to copy everything of `Customer` object to a new object so that I can safely modify the new object without affecting the original one.

To do this I have modified `clone` method of `Customer` class --

```
public Object clone() {
 Customer coned = null;
 try {
  cloned = super.cloned();
  clone.address = (Address) address.clone();
  return cloned; 
 } catch(CloneNotSupportedException e) {
   return null;
 }
}
```

This is the updated Address class --

```
class Address {
 String city;
 String state;
 public Object clone() 
  throws CloneNotSupportedException
 {
   return super.clone(); 
 }
}
```

Could anyone help me to understand what is the reason for not correctly cloning `address`
object.

Comment: You never call `.clone()` on your customer object.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the line for cloning while copying from my text editor. Modified my question. So the clone method was there when I was executing the program, however it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first of all: please just copy-paste the exact code from your IDE into your question. There are still a few issues in your code that will prevent it from compiling, surely copying it is a lot easier than typing it over?

The key problem you have is very easy: you never do anything. The only thing you do is call `super.clone()` throughout the hierarchy which will eventually result in `Object.clone()` being called (which will have no influence on your fields in your custom classes).

The solution? Add actual cloning logic in your `clone()` methods.

You can go the traditional route with the `Cloneable` interface and create it as such but there is no real need for this when you can simply create a new instance of the object with the available constructor(s), this will immediately sever every relationship between the two objects (aside from having equal values).

All you have to remember is to create a new instance for each reference type that's held as a field in the current layer.

If you're working with multiple layers (inheritance) then you have to remember to call `super.clone()` beforehand and implement your `clone()` method as well.

How does it work? Very easy, consider the following snippet:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Customer jack = new Customer("Jack", "Jackson");
        jack.setBalance(9001);

        Customer john = jack.clone();
        john.setBalance(1337);

        System.out.println("Jack's balance (name = " + jack.getFirstname()
                + "): " + jack.getBalance());
        System.out.println("John's balance (name = " + john.getFirstname()
                + "): " + john.getBalance());
    }
}

class Customer {
    private String firstname, lastname;
    private int balance;

    public Customer(String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        balance = 500;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(int b) {
        this.balance = b;
    }

    protected Customer clone() {
        Customer newCustomer = new Customer(getFirstname(), getLastname());
        newCustomer.setBalance(getBalance());
        return newCustomer;
    };
}
```

This result into this output:

> Jack's balance (name = Jack): 9001
>   John's balance (name = Jack): 1337

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I understand the fact that clone method was not correctly implemented.